# Stacked Bar with values

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

```
    +------------+------+------+---------+
    | promo_name | in   | out  | model   |
    +------------+------+------+---------+
    | A          | 0,87 | 0,13 | plan    |
    +------------+------+------+---------+
    | B          | 0,77 | 0,23 | plan    |
    +------------+------+------+---------+
    | C          | 0,54 | 0,46 | plan    |
    +------------+------+------+---------+
    | A          | 0,59 | 0,41 | predict |
    +------------+------+------+---------+
    | B          | 0,50 | 0,50 | predict |
    +------------+------+------+---------+
    | C          | 0,46 | 0,54 | predict |
    +------------+------+------+---------+
```

Hello. I have a dataframe as in the table above, I would like to draw a stacked barplot with values, for example:

[image]

But so far it only works like this, my code is below:

```
ratio.set_index(['promo_name', 'model'], inplace=True)
ratio = ratio.reindex(index = [('A', 'plan'), ('A', 'predict'),
                              ('B', 'plan'), ('B', 'predict'),
                              ('C', 'plan'), ('C', 'predict')])
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (12,5)
ratio.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
plt.xticks(rotation=30)
plt.show()
```

But until I get the wrong thing, how do I fix it?
[image: Bar plot]

Comment: @Parfait I want to see the values on the graph, and also for the columns from the same categories to be closer together, like (A, plan) and (A, predict)

Comment: I don't understand how you want the plot to look like. Do you want the numbers to show over the bars? Can you use an image editor to edit the plot to show what you want it to look like?

Comment: I added an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using matplotlib you can easily play around with the locations and widths of the bars:

```
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# plan, predict
Aout = (0.87, 0.59)
Ain = (0.13, 0.41)
Bout = (0.77, 0.50)
Bin = (0.23, 0.50)  
Cout = (0.54, 0.46)
Cin = (0.46, 0.54)
width = 1.0       # the width of the bars

A_positions = [0, 1]  # Positions for A bars
p1A = plt.bar([0, 1], (1.0, 1.0), width, color='g', label='out')
p2A = plt.bar([0, 1], Ain, width, color='b', label='in')

B_positions = [3, 4]  # Positions for B bars
p1B = plt.bar(B_positions, (1.0, 1.0), width, color='g')
p2B = plt.bar(B_positions, Bin, width, color='b')

C_positions = [6, 7]  # Positions for C bars
p1C = plt.bar(C_positions, (1.0, 1.0), width, color='g')
p2C = plt.bar(C_positions, Cin, width, color='b')

positions = A_positions + B_positions + C_positions  # All together for ticks
plt.xticks(positions, ('A (plan)', 'A (predict)', 'B (plan)', 'B (predict)', 'C (plan)', 'C (predict)'))
plt.xticks(rotation=70)
plt.yticks([1, 0])
plt.legend()
plt.tight_layout()
```

And add text labels (you can play around with the location):

```
plt.text(A_positions[0] - 0.25, Ain[0] / 2, str(Ain[0]))
plt.text(A_positions[0] - 0.25, Aout[0] / 2, str(Aout[0]))
plt.text(A_positions[1] - 0.25, Ain[1] / 2, str(Ain[1]))
plt.text(A_positions[1] - 0.25, Aout[1] / 2 + 0.5, str(Aout[1]))

plt.text(B_positions[0] - 0.25, Bin[0] / 2, str(Bin[0]))
plt.text(B_positions[0] - 0.25, Bout[0] / 2, str(Bout[0]))
plt.text(B_positions[1] - 0.25, Bin[1] / 2, str(Bin[1]))
plt.text(B_positions[1] - 0.25, Bout[1] / 2 + 0.5, str(Bout[1]))


plt.text(C_positions[0] - 0.25, Cin[0] / 2, str(Cin[0]))
plt.text(C_positions[0] - 0.25, Cout[0] / 2 + 0.5, str(Cout[0]))
plt.text(C_positions[1] - 0.25, Cin[1] / 2, str(Cin[1]))
plt.text(C_positions[1] - 0.25, Cout[1] / 2 + 0.5, str(Cout[1]))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is example with matplotlib usage.

Prepare source data:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

source = {'promo_name': {0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'C', 3: 'A', 4: 'B', 5: 'C'},  
         'in': {0: 0.87, 1: 0.77, 2: 0.54, 3: 0.59, 4: 0.5, 5: 0.46},
         'out': {0: 0.13, 1: 0.23, 2: 0.46, 3: 0.41, 4: 0.5, 5: 0.54},
         'model': {0: 'plan', 1: 'plan',2: 'plan', 3: 'predict', 4: 'predict', 5: 'predict'}}

ratio = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(source) 
ratio.head()

Out[1]:

         promo_name    in   out      model
    0   A            0.87  0.13   plan    
    1   B            0.77  0.23   plan    
    2   C            0.54  0.46   plan    
    3   A            0.59  0.41   predict 
    4   B            0.50  0.50   predict 
    5   C            0.46  0.54   predict
```

it's a solution:

```
ind = list(ratio.index)

plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (12,5)

bars_b = plt.bar(list(range(len(ind))), ratio['in'], width=0.3, color = 'b', label = 'in')
bars_r = plt.bar(list(range(len(ind))), ratio['out'], bottom = ratio['in'], width=0.3, color = 'r', label = 'out')

plt.xticks(rotation=30)
plt.legend()

for i in range(len(bars_b)):
    bar_b = bars_b[i]
    bar_r = bars_r[i]

    plt.gca().text(bar_b.get_x()+ bar_b.get_width()/2, 
                   bar_b.get_height()/2,
                   ratio['in'][i], 
                   ha='center', 
                   color = 'w')    

    plt.gca().text(bar_r.get_x()+ bar_r.get_width()/2, 
                   bar_r.get_height()/2 + bar_b.get_height(),ratio['out'][i], ha='center', color = 'w')


plt.show()
```

here result:

[image]

Comment: if you want to named  x-ticks, just cnahge this: plt.xticks(list(range(len(ind))), ind, rotation=30)